# Android Questonnaire layout approach

Tags: android

I want to create a questionnaire but I'm not sure what is the best way to approach this. I'm pretty new to Android but at the moment I have a working app which has a main activity screen which has various options. One of them is to launch the questionnaire. I have created a single database table which contains 4 columns Question Number, Question, Answer, Explanation. The explanation is displayed when the user selects the incorrect answer.

I am envisaging that the screen will be simple enough, just a textview containing the question and 3 buttons, 'YES' 'NO' 'BACK'. I plan to have 15 questions. What I'm wondering is do I have to create an activity for every question and every explanation even though the layout is going to be the same from one question to the next?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ultimately to get this to work I had to use a counter which I incremented after each successive question. No list was required.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not!

Do this the way you would in any other application.  Put your questions in some kind of list and iterate through them.  Set the content "question" view, in your layout with the successive values.

... and remember to save the position in the list across Pause and Resume!

Comment: Okay that sounds more realistic. So in onClick for the correct answer button I would have a for loop that sets the view based on the relevant question(i.e. the next question). I'll get started on it and report back. Also not sure exactly what you mean when you say "... and remember to save the position in the list across Pause and Resume!"

Comment: wrt onPause/onResume, welcome to Android.  You will know all about them, shortly.